# Android Studio: I want to create a filter icon on my toolbar on specific activity/fragment only, using recycle view

Tags: android-studio, toolbar, android-toolbar

This is the result that I want:

[image: Burger icon, "Family" string, 3 line icon and magnifying glass]

I want to create the filter icon however, I'm not sure if it's even possible. I've searched on youtube however, it's all regarding the search icon. I want the filter icon to be able to open a drawer, in which I'll be able to select what I want to filter. e.g alphabetical order/year, within the recycle view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create menu xml and can load those to the toolbar .  `onCreateOptionsMenu` can be used to inflate the menu and  `onOptionsItemSelected` will help to identify the click of the menu.
Refer : [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidActionBar/article.html)